# send request to outlook webservice via soapui

Tags: xml, web-services, xsd, outlook, soapui

I'm trying to send a simple request to Outlook Services using the "CreateItem" method. I have saved the following 3 files on my local directory:

Services.xml, messages.xsd, types.xsd

I'm loading services.xml (which is saved locally in my directory) to SoapUi program, and the wsdl seems to be fully loaded, but there is no URL Endpoint parameter. How can I retrieve such a parameter from the files or by starting outlook web services?

[image: no end point]

Answer (score 0):

You can update the WSDL from the server, which will both synchronize the definitions with the server and update the URL for the endpoint.

Select the endpoint - has the green icon next to it - right-click and select Update Definition [F5]. Specify the server name, and press OK.

Official [documentation](http://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/reference/wsdl-interface.html) is available.